# How to Pass a string (two words) having space to href link as query string

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fetch some values from db.Out of these values one column having string values with space(for ex: Amazon vc) and trying to pass that record as query string (by using href link).`Here $list_name contains value as Amazon India`

```
$nestedData[]= "<a href=$site_url/vcm/open_addvendorcode_popup.php?id3=$row[client_id]&id4
=$row[list_name]&id5=$row[auto_list_id]&id6=$row[id] id='1' data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#add_vendorcode_popup$row[edit_id]>Add VC</a>";
```

When I click on the above link, I can see in url with incomplete List name as Amazon and after list_name,`&id5=$row[auto_list_id]&id6=$row[id]` this part got missed. `I am dispalying this data by using datatable`. And when I see by using Inspect Element `&list_name=Amazon" India=""`, but this should display like `&list_name="Amazon India"`. I can not change the data in DB, because it was already inserted. So how can I fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Here thie issue is data got missed while displaying when we mouse over on href link.

Comment: Because it is not encoded properly for a URL. And you want to quote the URL `href='$site_url/vcm/open_addvendorcode_popup.php?id3=$row[client_id]&id4
=$row[list_name]&id5=$row[auto_list_id]&id6=$row[id]'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Updates only first name instead of full name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901569/mysql-updates-only-first-name-instead-of-full-name)

Comment: ^The issue on that dup is not related to Mysql. It relates to the browser and spaces as this question does.

Comment: Yes, but when I add urlencode function `&list_name='".urlencode($row[list_name])."'` it is opening directly on browser instead of displaying bootstrap modal popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'm going to expand on @AbraCadaver's comment:

### Explanation:

First what you need to do is store the url into a variable like this:

```
$url = "{$site_url}/vcm/open_addvendorcode_popup.php?id3={$row[client_id]}&id4={$row[list_name]}&id5={$row[auto_list_id]}&id6={$row[id]}"
```

Then you want to encode the url using `urlencode`:

```
$url_encoded = urlencode($url);
```

Then you want to use the **encoded** url within the `href` attribute of the HTML element:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url_encoded; ?>" id='1' data-toggle='modal' data-target="<?php echo '#add_vendorcode_popup' . $row[edit_id]; ?>" >Add VC</a>
```

### Shorthand:

Optionally, you can make this shorter like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo urlencode({$site_url}/vcm/open_addvendorcode_popup.php?id3={$row[client_id]}&id4={$row[list_name]}&id5={$row[auto_list_id]}&id6={$row[id]}); ?>" id='1' data-toggle='modal' data-target="<?php echo '#add_vendorcode_popup' . $row[edit_id]; ?>" >Add VC</a>
```

Comment: `Urlencode($row['list_name']);` is working .you mentioned `url_endode()`.. please check. Any way after changing to `Urlencode()`,it is working. Thank you